# BigQuery Timestamp in Select giving different format

Tags: google-bigquery

using BigQuery query API to retrieve data from BigQuery. for timestamp column , am getting values in different format.

```
query="select * from table"
QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig = QueryJobConfiguration
                    .newBuilder(query)
                    .setUseLegacySql(false)
                    .build();
```

Value in Table : `"2022-02-25 08:47:48.801665"`
Value in Output : `1.645778868801665E9`

If I am casting to string the getting proper value. why is this happening ?
can someone explain ?

Comment: What programming language are you using? Depending on the language is how you are supposed to cast the information.

Comment: I am using Java.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert to `TIMESTAMP`, because it takes `milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00 UTC`. That's why you are getting   this result.

You can convert this result to TIMESTAMP using this formula `timestamp.toInstant().toEpochMilli() * 1000`.

You can see this example:

```
QueryParameterValue.timestamp(
                      // Timestamp takes microseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00 UTC
                      timestamp.toInstant().toEpochMilli() * 1000))
```

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-query-params-timestamps#bigquery_query_params_timestamps-java) is more documentation about it.

If you want to cast from BigQuery. You have some options.

`CAST` the `TIMESTAMP` columns.

```
SELECT CAST(DATE("2022-02-25 08:47:48.801665") AS TIMESTAMP )
```

`CAST` `TIMESTAMP` to [STRING](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp).

```
SELECT STRING(TIMESTAMP "2022-02-25 08:47:48.801665", "UTC") AS string;
```

Give some [format](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#format_timestamp).

```
SELECT FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%c", TIMESTAMP "2022-02-25 08:47:48.801665", "UTC") AS formatted;
```

You can see more documentation about [CAST](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually I am not using named parameters. I am facing issues in Selecting timestamp column. if I am doing a select then I am getting value in Exponential format.